# What is the difference between covariance and correlation?

Tags: correlation, variance, covariance

I am analysing stock returns and whether they move in the same or opposite directions across different regions, investment styles or company sizes.

Which of the covariance or the correlation gives the best measure of this? And what is the difference between what both statistical tests tell you?

Comment: In what sense do you intend us to understand "best measure"?

Comment: Neither covariance nor correlation are statistical tests, so the second question is not too clear as well.

Comment: which of the two mathematical methods would be best for figuring out how the movements in prices of two stocks are related? And if possible, would you be able to give a simple definition of the two methods please?

Comment: Essentially it seems to me that they both do the same job and tell you the same thing, am I wrong?

Comment: For real data, covariance has units; correlation is a pure number with no units. For example if you are expressing the association between cost of building roads and their various lengths, correlation is the same whether its dollars & miles or euros & km.

Comment: So which one do you recommend I use?

Comment: Or put it this way - if I check the correlation between the two stock returns, it would tell me when stock a rises whether stock b rises or falls (or no relationship). If I check the covariance, what would it tell me?