# Could somebody please explain covariance to me

Tags: correlation, covariance, cross-correlation

I feel kinda embarrassed to ask this question but for some reason I can't figure it out, so please help if you can

My dissertation involves two stock return datasets and essentially I am testing the relationships between the two stock returns. Calculating the correlation coefficient tells me when stock A rises, whether stock B rises, falls or is unrelated, as well as showing how strong the relationship is. What would calculating the covariance tell me?

Comment: Essentially a repeat of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462766/what-is-the-difference-between-covariance-and-correlation As explained there in different words the correlation between two variables is the covariance divided by the products of the two standard deviations. Covariance is not useful unless you want a measure with units.

Comment: See our [higher-rated posts on covariance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covariance?tab=Votes) for answers to your question.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to CV, dakofsta. I do not think you should feel embarased about the (perhaps) less-intuitive meaning of covariance. You should *definitely* check out those recommended questions and answers, though!

Comment: It has answered it for me, thanks :) 

I was embarrassed because I asked a similar question before and didn't get a clear answer but got downvotes on my question so assumed everybody thought I was being stupid

Comment: Understood, but asking the same question again is discouraged and is unlikely to get a better answer as far as you are concerned. The way to encourage a better answer is to edit the original question and to engage with commenters explaining what you don't understand or why their remarks don't meet your needs. My wild guess is that  the **single** downvoter was flagging lack of research effort in just reposting. People here don't call each other "stupid".